# MVC bundling with minification and require.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, requirejs

I am building a MVC application and using angular and require.js in it.

I have defined my JS files as below.

**First JS File:**

```
define(function (require) {
    'use strict';
     var angular = require('angular');
     var app = angular.module('App');

     app.service('Service1', function () {
     });
});
```

**Second JS File:**

```
define(function (require) {
    'use strict';
     var angular = require('angular');
     var app = angular.module('App');

     app.service('Service2', function () {
     });
});
```

In the require js configuration , I gave the path of the script bundle and could see JS files are bundled and minified and is loaded. But we are getting an error "**Service2 is not defined**".

When i merge the two files or remove "**define(function (require)**" from the individual files then everything is working fine.

**Merged File:**

```
define(function (require) {
    'use strict';
     var angular = require('angular');
     var app = angular.module('App');

     app.service('Service1', function () {
     });

     app.service('Service2', function () {
     });
});
```

**First JS File:**

```
    'use strict';
     var angular = require('angular');
     var app = angular.module('App');

     app.service('Service1', function () {
     });
```

**Second JS File:**

```
    'use strict';
     var angular = require('angular');
     var app = angular.module('App');

     app.service('Service2', function () {
     });
```

I cannot merge the files as above since i have huge list of JS files.

I am not 100% sure what would be the impact if i remove "**define(function (require)**".

What would be best approach to use MVC's bundling and minification feature in my scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to define does not run until it is required by something else. So your service 2 is not defined error is probably because you haven't explicitly required it.

```
require(['First', 'Second'], function () {
    //Use Service1 and Service2
});
```